# NumPy load file interspersed with headers

Tags: python, performance, file, parsing, numpy

I'm trying to parse files with repeating blocks of the following format:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
5000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
4200
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp ff
0 47.6892
0 41.3
-11.434 84.1378
ITEM: ATOMS id type z vx 
5946 27 11.8569 0.00180946 
5948 28 11.1848 -0.0286474 
5172 27 12.1796 0.00202046 
...
```

where ... will be *NUMBER OF ATOMS* entries (4200 for this particular file). Each file contains many of these blocks in succession and will range from 1-5 million lines.

I want to completely ignore all of the header data contained in the first 9 lines of each block and only need an array containing all of the "z" values (3rd column in a data entry) and an array containing the "vx" values (4th column in a data entry).

The headers  for each block will always be the same within a file except for the number following the ITEM: TIMESTEP entry. The header format will remain the same across files and the files differ only in the number of entries (atoms).

I wrote some incredibly dirty code that did the trick for some shorter files I was working with previously but it's very slow for these files. I tried using the genfromtxt function but I haven't found a way to bend it to do what I want in this case. Any tips on making this faster?

EDIT:

The following worked for me:

```
grep -E '^[.-0123456789]+ [.-0123456789]+ [.-0123456789]+ [.-0123456789]'
```

As did this:

```
with open(data, 'r') as fh:
    wrapper = (i for i in fh if re.match(r'^[-.1234567890]+ [-.1234567890]+ [-.1234567890]+ [-.1234567890]',i))
    z_vx = np.genfromtxt(wrapper, usecols=(2,3))
```

This ended up being the fastest for my case:

```
regexp = r'\d+\s+\d+\s+([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s+([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s+\n'
data = np.fromregex(file_path, regexp, dtype=[('z', float), ('vx', float)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want speed, you can `grep` only the relevant lines and then use `np.genfromtxt()`.

grep something like this (you assumed the relevant rows have 4 fields of numbers right?):

```
grep -P '^[-.0123456789]+ [-.0123456789]+ [-.0123456789]+ [-.0123456789]+$'
```

A more pythonic solution would be to wrap the file handle with a generator like this:

```
wrapper = (i for i in fh if re.match(r'^[-.1234567890]+ [-.1234567890]+ [-.1234567890]+ [-.1234567890]+$',i))
np.genfromtxt(wrapper,...)
```

Comment: Had to remove the '+$' at the end and use '-E' instead of '-P' but worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Ended up using `sed` so add a `#` in front of the header and then use `np.loadtxt`.

So the bash script was

```
for i in $( ls *.data )
   do
     b = `basename $i .data`
     sed '1,9{/^#/!s/^/#/}' $i > $b.tmp
     rm $i
     mv $b.tmp $i
   done
```

and the in python

```
from numpy import loadtxt
data = loadtxt("atoms.data")
```

Comment: I think our scenarios are a bit different. Looks like you have multiple files each with one header in the first 9 lines, correct?

I have those headers repeated many times throughout each of my files.

Comment: Yes, the loop in bash was only if you had multiple files, but it would be easy to implement with only one file.
I'm not sure what to do if the header comes again. Then you should use of the other's answers.